# How to change dynamically the index name in “saveJsonToES”?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to insert logs that I extract from a kafka server in order to insert in ElasticSearc 5 with Spark Streaming 2.0.0 .

Here is my code. My big problem is with line "saveJsonToES", in fact, this function has a string argument for specifying the index name. However, my index name is a JavaDStream. I did like this in oder to generate dynamic index names in another class.

```
JavaDStream<List<String>> newLines = lines.map(arg0 -> {    

        String lineToInsertInES = "";
        String indexName = "";
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        //some code to determine strings to add in my list

        list.add(lineToInsertInES);
        list.add(indexName);
        return list;
    });

    JavaDStream<String> lineToInsertInES = newLines.map(list -> list.get(0));
    JavaDStream<String> indexName = newLines.map(list -> list.get(1));

    lineToInsertInES.foreachRDD(line->{

        if(!line.isEmpty())
            JavaEsSpark.saveJsonToEs(line,indexName); //problem at this line
    });
```

Can you telle how I can solve this ?

Thank you in advance

J

Comment: any idea plzzz ??

Comment: How u implemented at last... Looking for something similar